# sorting datatable based on column index not name of column

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable which has 10 columns, I would like to sort the table by a column index 10 from largest to smallest. I know this should be easy for some but this is my first time using such a DataTable

all the website that i have found all say that you have to know the column name but i dont have that and would like to make reference to the column by the index value of the column. which should sort all the rows in that datatble

Comment: What problem(s) do you have exactly? What have you tried so far and failed?

Comment: Which ever sit that i have found always just reference to the column name and the data does not sort itself.

Comment: Try DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Then fill values                 
    DataView dv = dt.AsDataView();
    dv.Sort = dv.Table.Columns[index].ColumnName + " DESC";

Comment: post your code so we can see what you have tried

Comment: will this sort the data for the one time or would it keep the sorted data in the same datatable

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DefaultView and the ColumnName to sort.

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = dataTable.Columns[9].ColumnName + " DESC";
```

Working example:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //Define columns to DataTable 
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");


    //Adding rows to DataTable 
    DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
    row1["ID"] = 1;
    row1["Name"] = "Jack";
    dt.Rows.Add(row1);


    DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();
    row2["ID"] = 2;
    row2["Name"] = "Fruit";
    dt.Rows.Add(row2);

    DataRow row3 = dt.NewRow();
    row3["ID"] = 3;
    row3["Name"] = "Ball";
    dt.Rows.Add(row3);

    dt.DefaultView.Sort = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName + " ASC";

    foreach (DataRowView drv in dt.DefaultView)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(drv[i]);
    }
```

Comment: will this order the rows of data

Comment: it sorts the rows in the DefaultView

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
//Then fill values 
DataView dv = dt.AsDataView(); // DataView dv = dt.DefaultView();
dv.Sort = dv.Table.Columns[index].ColumnName + " DESC";
dt = dv.Table;
```

Comment: Error Message Can not find column

Comment: @JimBrad Instead of `DataView dv = dt.AsDataView();` try `DataView dv = new DataView(); dv = dt.DefaultView();`

Comment: now it runs the program without any issues but yet it still doesnt sort the data