# datatable not sorting no errors

Tags: c#, datatable

I am using the code below to  sort my data the program runs with out any isses but the data in the rows is not being sorted.. and cant find a reason why this would be the case.

```
DataTable extractedData = new DataTable();
//data added to datatable extractedData
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv =extractedData.AsDataView();
dv.Sort = dv.Table.Columns[10].ColumnName + "  DESC";
extractedData = dv.Table;
```

This code below is using `apose.slides` to add code into a presentation table.

```
 string val = "";
 int col = 0;
 int row = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (j == 0)
         {
             val = extractedData.Rows[row][valuesUsed[col]].ToString();
             string[] removeQuestion = val.Split('[', ']');
             val = removeQuestion[1];
         }
         else
         {
             val = extractedData.Rows[row][valuesUsed[col]].ToString();
             if (val == "-" || val == "")
             {
                 val = extractedData.Rows[row][valuesUsed[col]].ToString();
             }
             else
             {
                 val = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(extractedData.Rows[row][valuesUsed[col]]), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
             }
         }
         table[j, i].TextFrame.Text = val;
         col++;
     }
     row++;
     col = 0;
 }
```

Comment: How you are showing the data?? post that line too

Comment: this isnt a line of code as the data has to be added to w word doc

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13762423/1577396) to your previous question should work.. did you check it?

Comment: yes.. the output has not chnaged and the results are all over the place

Comment: @JimBrad ok change your last line to `extractedData = dv.toTable();` instead of `extractedData = dv.Table;`

Comment: I have trie4d non of them methods wor

Comment: @JimBrad I think you are mentioning the wrong column Index.. mention `9` instead of `10`.

Comment: @Mr_Greeen u were right about chnaging to the method call

Comment: @JimBrad so did this solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work :-

```
DataView dv = extractedData.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = extractedData.Columns[10].ColumnName + "  DESC";
```

You were required to make the DataView the DataTables default view inorder for it to work.

Here's a link you should check out too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx

Comment: No worries. You dont need that last line in your code @Mr_Green.

Comment: The OP is working with `extractedData` so adding the `DefaultView` to the `extractedData`.. isnt it correct?

Comment: extractedData is the DataTable, your assigning the DataView as its Defaultview, therefore you don't need that last line of code. Try it.

Comment: extractedData = dv.toTable(); isnt required.

Comment: No, it is necessary.. If you are doing `extractedData.DefaultView.Sort = dataTable.Columns[9].ColumnName + " DESC";` in one line then it is not necessary..

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line of your code to [`dv.toTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f.aspx) instead of `dv.Table`.

```
DataTable extractedData = new DataTable();
//data added to datatable extractedData
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv = extractedData.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "ColumnName  DESC";   //mention exact name of your column
//or else
//dv.Sort = extractedData.Columns[9].ColumnName + "  DESC";
extractedData = dv.toTable();  //Instead of dv.Table;
```

For information go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987217/1577396).